Splitting token lists on underscores
The following LaTeX3 ode works as expected:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {4^2_text}
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {_} \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq

in that it splits \l_tmpa_tl on the underscore character. Unfortunately, , as shown below, the splitting fails when I wrap this inside some code the code fails to split \l_tmpa_tl on the underscore. I have tried using \c_underscore_str but this doesn't help.
Does anyone know how to split \l_tmpa_tl on the underscore in the \__parse:n code below?
\documentclass{amsart}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NnV}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__parse:n #1
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {_} \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq  % does NOT split \l_tmpa_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand\Parse{ m }
{
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \__parse:n {##1} }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

  \ExplSyntaxOn
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {4^2_text}
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {_} \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq % works as expected
  \ExplSyntaxOff

  \Parse{ 4^2_text }

\end{document}


Inside the document _ has category code 8 (barring packages that change it). Inside \ExplSyntaxOn it has category code 11.
\documentclass{amsart}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {Ne}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__parse:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nen \l_tmpa_seq { \char_generate:nn {`_} {8} } {#1}
    \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\Parse{ m }
  {
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \__parse:n {##1} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\Parse{ 4^2_text }

\end{document}

Output on the console
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {4^2}
>  {text}.

You can also set the catcode to the current value.
\documentclass{amsart}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {Ne}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__parse:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nen \l_tmpa_seq { \__pi_uscatcode: } {#1}
    \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
  }

\cs_new:Nn \__pi_uscatcode: { \char_generate:nn {`_} { \char_value_catcode:n {`\_} } }

\NewDocumentCommand\Parse{ m }
  {
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \__parse:n {##1} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\Parse{ 4^2_text }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\Parse{ 4^2_text }

\catcode`_=12

\Parse{ 4^2_text }

\end{document}

Output on the console
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {4^2}
>  {text}.
<recently read> }

l.26 \Parse{ 4^2_text }

?
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {4^2}
>  {text}.
<recently read> }

l.29 \Parse{ 4^2_text }

?
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {4^2}
>  {text}.
<recently read> }


Nice. Why doesn't it work with \c_underscore_str?

@jlab Because \c_underscore_str yields an underscore with category code 12.

Can we use \c_math_superscript_token instead?

@jlab No: try it.

Well, in fact I tried. But I don't understand why it doesn't work. Isn't \c_math_subscript_token designed to hold an underscore with category code 8?

@jlab _ (with category code 8) and \c_math_subscript_token have the same meaning, but they're not the same token. If you're asked to read a text and to stop at the word “freedom” you don't stop at the word “liberty”. A more TeX example: { (catcode 1) and \bgroup have the same meaning, but you can't do \def\foo\bgroup x}

Many thanks for all these precisions.

Thanks for the clear explanation and solution! I realised that in my actual use-case I should be using \peek_charcode:NTF, which both simplifies my code and makes it more general.
